# Using webpack to build a dependency before compiling the build

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using inline styles & my theme comes from a file called `themes.json`, which I create & inject into my `build` folder before calling webpack. I'd like webpack to handle this, too.

My first attempt was to use a plugin:

```
compiler.plugin('compilation', async(compilation, callback) => {
  const themes = {}; // empty for this example
  compilation.assets['themes.json'] = {
    source: function() {
      return themes;
    },
    size: function() {
      return themes.length;
    }
  };
  callback();
}
```

However, since plugins run async or parallel, I come across a race condition where my `index.js` that has a `const themes = require('../build/themes.json')` is trying to require something before it exists.

How can I make sure `themes.json` exists and is useable within my build? I see 3 possibilities:

1. There's a way to run plugins in serial that I don't know about
2. I somehow use a loader to perform this
3. I write a plugin that looks for `require('../build/themes.json')` and when it finds it, it creates & injects the themes.

Any help on the right way to do this?